# What version of the AIC should be used in total least squares regression?

Tags: regression, aic, total-least-squares

If we are carrying out a regression and we have errors in both the x-s and y-s, we can estimate the parameter values using the total least squares method. In that case, I assume we shouldn't use the AIC or AICc, as they are for use where the x-s are deterministic and there are errors in the y-s. My question is: What version of the AIC, if there is one, should be used where we have errors in both the x-s and y-s, and where we've calibrated the models using total least squares?

I did several searches on Google but didn't come up with anything that was the least bit encouraging!

Comment: Interesting question. The AIC is just adjusting the likelihood for the flexibility of the model to fit the data. If you had the likelihood correct (ie you took into account both x & y), I would think you'd be OK.